# How to send file from Web Application to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking, pi-2, web-server, node.js

I am working on a project which I have to send file from my Web Application(Node.js) to multiple Raspberry Pis.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to send file generated by the Web App to those Raspberry Pis. Is there any possible way to do this?

I appreciate all of your help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

If all your Raspberry Pi's are running Nodejs, they can all exchange information via HTTP. In particular, consider a [REST protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) design for exchanging information and control between peer Pi's. REST lets you do a lot with your Pi farm.

If you just want to send a file, consider [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy), which is simpler but may be what you asked for.